# DistributionNotFound when trying to install ZRS

Tags: plone, zope, buildout

I have a site with Plone 4.2.5 in which I want to install ZRS.

I added the `[zrs]` extra to the `zeoserver` part:

```
[zeoserver]
recipe = plone.recipe.zeoserver[zrs]
```

I also pinned the right versions of the recipes and packages involved:

```
[versions]
plone.recipe.zeoserver = 1.2.8
plone.recipe.zope2instance = 4.2.18
Twisted = 15.4.0
zc.zrs = 2.4.4
```

But, when I run buildout, I get the following error:

```
$ bin/buildout
...
While:
  Installing.

An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/plone/my.project/eggs/zc.buildout-2.4.3-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1992, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/home/plone/my.project/eggs/zc.buildout-2.4.3-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 565, in install
    self._compute_part_signatures(install_parts)
  File "/home/plone/my.project/eggs/zc.buildout-2.4.3-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 810, in _compute_part_signatures
    sig = _dists_sig(pkg_resources.working_set.resolve([req]))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 839, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
DistributionNotFound: The 'zc.zrs' distribution was not found and is required by plone.recipe.zeoserver
```

The exact same thing runs fine in Plone 4.3.

I'm using the following versions also:

```
[versions]
setuptools = 18.3.2
zc.buildout = 2.4.3
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add "plone.recipe.zeoserver[zrs]" to your eggs section.

See https://github.com/kitconcept/buildout.zrs for an example of a working master/slave setup.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, are you sure that's working with Plone 4.2? the documentation of that package mentions Plone 4.3.1.

Comment: I just tried Plone 4.3. Have you tried to just checkout the repo and run it with Plone 4.2.x?

Comment: In fact it works in Plone 4.2 also and, BTW, there's no need to add those eggs to the `eggs` section neither; I think my problem is different, it seems to be related with setuptools or zc.buildout versions.